# jqGrid - I have a column say ColumnA but needs to load from a different list for the Add Form

Tags: jqgrid

In the grid I show "Column A" field from a user editable database table via a java servlet returning XML type.  But when the user clicks on the "Add", I need this field "Column A" in the add form to be a select list that is loaded from a different database table, e.g. a lookup/reference table that allows the user to choose from a list of available values.  How can I do that? Is there way to set a data URL that loads a field but only that particular field in the Add Form only?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if I understand correctly the question..

but i think you need in col model to define the edit type and edit dataUrl..

Try this

```
{
     name:'Column A',
     index:'Column A',          
     editable:true,
     edittype:'select',
     editoptions:{
          dataUrl:'your/url/for/data/data.php'          
     }     
}
```